# Using spotify-web-api-node to generate an authentication token

Tags: node.js, spotify

I am new to using nodejs and am working on a project where I can make a custom playlist by adding one song at a time via a search. I've been able to get the code to do the searching and grabbing the proper ids done, but when trying to add to the playlist, I'm getting an error about the scope being wrong. Long story short, I was doing the wrong type of authentication.

So I read up on the spotify-web-api-node documents, but I'm getting lost between generating the authorization url and then getting the response, which is then used by another method to get the authorization token. I'm not sure if there is another method I'm not seeing that will make the request, or if I'm just supposed to do a regular request out via normal node methods.

The code I'm using is pretty much a copy-paste from the following link (https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node#authorization), where the second box with the header "The below uses a hardcoded authorization code..." is where I'm lost... I need to get that code from the response, but I'm not sure how I'm to send the request to even get the response, the createAuthorizeURL method just seems to make the actual url but not send it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the confusion stems from the way the [Authorization Code flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow) works, and the way I've written the documentation for the node wrapper. The purpose of the createAuthorizeURL method is to help you create the URL that you need to forward the user to.

From the same piece of documentation that you linked to:

```
In order to get permissions, you need to direct the user to our Accounts service. 
Generate the URL by using the wrapper's authorization URL method.
```

So let's say that the user starts out by entering your site, http://www.jd.example.com. It'll have a Spotify styled button that says *Login here*. The button links to the URL that the createAuthorizeURL has generated. One very important part of the URL is the redirect_uri query parameter. For example, the URL that you would generate would look something like

```
https://accounts.spotify.com:443/authorize?client_id=5fe01282e44241328a84e7c5cc169165&
response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://www.jd.example.com/callback&
scope=playlist-modify-public
```

When the user clicks the button they will be taken through the authentication and authorization flow on Spotify's site (accounts.spotify.com/). However, when they've finished this flow, they will be directed by Spotify to the same redirect_uri that you gave in the createAuthorizeURL, e.g. https://www.jd.example.com/callback.

This means that your web server (e.g. [Express](http://expressjs.com/)) needs to be able to handle a request to the redirect_uri. If your web server was indeed Express, it may look like this.

```
/* Some express.js setup here */
/* Some spotify-web-api-node setup here */

/* Handle authorization callback from Spotify */
app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {

  /* Read query parameters */
  var code  = req.query.code; // Read the authorization code from the query parameters
  var state = req.query.state; // (Optional) Read the state from the query parameter

  /* Get the access token! */
  spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code)
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log('The token expires in ' + data['expires_in']);
      console.log('The access token is ' + data['access_token']);
      console.log('The refresh token is ' + data['refresh_token']);

      /* Ok. We've got the access token!
         Save the access token for this user somewhere so that you can use it again.
         Cookie? Local storage?
      */

      /* Redirecting back to the main page! :-) */
      res.redirect('/');

    }, function(err) {
      res.status(err.code);
      res.send(err.message);
    }
  });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Michael, it helps a lot. So if I understand this correctly, there wouldn't be a way for me to load my program and have a totally hand-free run; meaning the user could store their spotify name/password in a config and the program could do it's own auth. They will always have to click the button, correct?

It's not a deal breaker if that's the case, I just don't want to keep running down that road if it's just a dead end.

Comment: No, that's right. It's simply not the way [OAuth 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/) works, which the Web API supports. For security reasons, the user needs to be taken to Spotify's site for authentication and authorization, and then directed back to your application. However, they only need to authorize your application once. When authorized, your application will receive an access token that will be valid for one hour. After that, it needs to be refreshed. Since you can refresh a token forever, the user only needs to go through the login flow once.

Comment: Would this method also work with the `spotify-web-api-js` node module?